# How to create datatable column dynamically using Enumerable.Range?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a C# Datatable (not DataTables.net library). This table has 5 columns

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("1", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("2", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("3", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("4", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("5", typeof(int));
```

Is it possible to use LINQ Enumerable.Range to create it instead? I tried below but I can't see the column created.

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => table.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(string)));
```

Comment: Don't use LINQ for functions that produce side effects. A simple `for` will do here. (You can do a `foreach` on `Enumerable.Range` if you insist, but that's not any easier or more readable.)

Comment: Why just don't write simple `for` or `foreach` loop?

Comment: yeah i can use for loop but wondering if it possible with Enumerable.Range

Comment: Certainly -- just add `.ToArray()` to your expression and done. The `.Select()` does nothing as written because LINQ uses lazy evaluation. This is another reason why you don't really want to use functions with side effects in LINQ. Don't get too hung up on producing oneliners, and try using LINQ for "getting things", not "doing things".

Comment: @JeroenMostert okay noted. thanks for the tips :)

Comment: You could also do something like 

table.Columns.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1,5)
.Select(i => new DataColumn(i.ToString(), typeof(string)))
.ToArray());

Comment: @ericpat Good, but `typeof(int)`.

Comment: @NetMage true, in the first snippet. In the Enumerable.Range snippet it is typeof(string) That is what was scrolled into view when I made my comment.

Comment: @ericpat PS I prefer `.Count()` to `.ToArray()`. Or better still, my processing extension method `ForEach` with no argument - but mostly I prefer `for` and not using LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Add an [immediate execution method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution) (`ToList()`, `ToArray()`) to the end of the query.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("1", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("2", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("3", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("4", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("5", typeof(int));

Enumerable.Range(6, 5)
    .Select(i => table.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), typeof(string)))
    .ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not a fan of using LINQ with side effects. The function of `ToList` isn't clear and the next developer may feel inclined to remove it. Code based on `table.Columns.AddRange` would be more self-explanatory. -- As said in the comments, I see now.

Comment: @GertArnold I'm a fan) This cool thing is one of the reasons why I chose .NET

Comment: Still, it's using LINQ out of the functional-programming paradigm it's based on. Possible, but not recommended.